# Co Authoring with different positions

Tags: author, multi-author

Is it possible to assign many authors to a post and specify the contribution type of each one with some labels like: writer, translator, author, reviewer etc.

I tried the plugin Co-Authors Plus, but it assumes every user assigned to an article is an author.

PS:

- The contribution type of a user may differ from a post to another one, for example, he may be a translator for post X and writer for post Y.
- I need to attach a real user (wp_users) to a post as an author but specify its contribution type. I want to get for example in a post:

  ```
  Authors: user1
  Translators: user2, user3
  Reviewers: user4
  ```

Comment: you can add the data in custom fields. on the administration of the post, go up right and select "custom fields". if you add a custom field "writerName", you can use it in the template with `$post->writerName`

Comment: it is not clear what is the question here. The most simple solution is to just write the names as part of the post....

Comment: But what if I change the name of the user, it won't be updated systematically inside the post content. I need to assign a user to a post and say that he has written it, or translated it …

Comment: ... which is why I said the question is not clear. It is totally obvious there should be other requirements as well, not only to show names

Comment: Question Edited.

Answer (score 0):

I found a correct answer. I ended by adding custom fields (translators, reviewers ...) with the ACF plugin. Example:

```
    Field Label: Translators
    Field Name: translators
    Field type: Relational (user)
    Field Type: multi-select
    ..
```

However, this will make the table wp_postmeta very huge, as my website will contain a large number of posts.